# Primitive constructors vs casting for conversion

Tags: c++, constructor, casting

What is the difference between:

```
long myLong;
float myFloat = (float) myLong;
```

and:

```
float myFloat = float(myLong);
```

Comment: Duplicate, but cannot find it. :|

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference except for syntax, but in C++ you should really be using the [templated casting functions](https://web.archive.org/web/20070929132736/http://www.acm.org/crossroads/xrds3-1/ovp3-1.html)

Comment: Why should we be using template casting functions?